# How to align these html items so the canvases are in a row and centered with the arrows and the last div to be centered as well

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

I am trying to make the the canvasses with the arrows to display in a row and to be entered horizontally and vertically. I want this flex row to have no wrap and also underneath it I want to put a div which as well is centered horizontally and vertically (order-item).

As of now what happens is that the canvasses show up funky and the div that goes underneath does not have the text inside the div and it is not centered.

(P.S. The canvases contain 3D models loaded from angular and those {{}} are variables don't worry about it the rest is normal html and css).

I will put the code for the respective files in here.

HTML:

```
<div class="containerFlex">
  <div class="canvas">
      <canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <span>--></span>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas">
      <canvas #canvasTwo id="canvasTwo"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <p>-----></p>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas">
      <canvas #canvasThree id="canvasThree"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <p>-----></p>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas">
      <canvas #canvasFour id="canvasFour"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <p>-----></p>
    </div>
    <div class="canvasFive">
      <canvas #canvasFive id="canvasFive"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <p>-----></p>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas">
      <canvas #canvasSix id="canvasSix"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="containerTest">
  <div *ngFor="let order of data" class="order-item">
    <p>{{order.manuf}}</p>
    <p>{{order.cpu}}</p>
    <p>{{order.gpu}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!--
Would be awesome if I could make each block collapsible and with the default text of Block and then upon
expanding it I can see the info inside.
What I want is to have both the canvases centered nicely and also the containerTest centered, also each new div has to go downwards
-->
```

CSS:

```
.containerTest{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height:200px;
  width: 600px;
}

.order-item{
  background-color: green;
  height:200px;
  width: 600px;
}

.containerFlex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.canvas{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Optional, for those curious how I loaded in the 3D models:

.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader, GLTF } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { CSS2DRenderer } from 'three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "@angular/fire/compat/database";
import {Observable, of, Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {FireConectionService} from "../fire-conection.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-blockchain-game',
  templateUrl: './blockchain-game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blockchain-game.component.css']
})



/* 3D Code part */


export class BlockchainGameComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('canvas') private canvasRef!: ElementRef; //House
  @ViewChild('canvasTwo') private canvasTwoRef!: ElementRef; //Store
  @ViewChild('canvasThree') private canvasThreeRef!: ElementRef; //building_2 (shipping)
  @ViewChild('canvasFour') private canvasFourRef!: ElementRef; //Factory
  @ViewChild('canvasFive') private canvasFiveRef!: ElementRef; //Tower
  @ViewChild('canvasSix') private canvasSixRef!: ElementRef; //Bank


  @Input() public fieldOfView: number = 1;

  @Input('nearClipping') public nearClippingPane: number = 1;

  @Input('farClipping') public farClippingPane: number = 2000;

  private camera!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

  private cameraTwo!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

  private cameraThree!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

  private cameraFour!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

  private cameraFive!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

  private cameraSix!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

  private controls!: OrbitControls;

  private controlsTwo!: OrbitControls; // Controls for the second model

  private ambientLight!: THREE.AmbientLight;

  private light1!: THREE.PointLight;

  private light2!: THREE.PointLight;

  private light3!: THREE.PointLight;

  private light4!: THREE.PointLight;

  private model: any;
  private modelTwo:any;
  private modelThree:any;
  private modelFour:any;
  private modelFive:any;
  private modelSix:any;

  private directionalLight!: THREE.DirectionalLight;

/*
  Blockchain code
 */

  dataBase: AngularFireDatabase;
  gameData$: Observable<any[]> = of([]);
  data : any[] | undefined;
  gameDataSubscription: Subscription | undefined;
  manuf!:string;
  cpu!:string;
  gpu!:string;
  orderC:number= 0;

  constructor(private router: Router, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private fireConnectionService: FireConectionService) {
    //initialize database
    this.dataBase = db;
  }

  retrieveData(){
    //create the reference towards the data list
    const orders = this.db.list("orders");
    //define the table as the data of the users table
    this.gameData$ = orders.valueChanges();

    //if the data subscription is not subbed yet then sub
    if(!this.gameDataSubscription){
      this.gameDataSubscription = this.gameData$.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('Data updated:', data);
        //update method
        this.data = data;

        //add number of valid players
        if(this.data){
          this.manuf = "";
          this.cpu = "";
          this.gpu = "";

          let counter = 1;

          this.data.forEach((order) => {
            if(order.manuf != "" && order.gpu != "" && order.cpu != ""){
              this.manuf = order.manuf;
              this.cpu = order.cpu;
              this.gpu = order.gpu; //get the things
            }

            /*if(counter == 2){
              this.manuf = order.manuf;
              this.cpu = order.cpu;
              this.gpu = order.gpu;
            }else{
              counter++;
            }*/


          });
        }
      });
    }

  }

  private get canvas(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
  }

  private get canvasTwo(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasTwoRef.nativeElement;
  }

  private get canvasThree(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasThreeRef.nativeElement;
  }

  private get canvasFour(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasFourRef.nativeElement;
  }
  private get canvasFive(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasFiveRef.nativeElement;
  }
  private get canvasSix(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasSixRef.nativeElement;
  }


  private loaderGLTF = new GLTFLoader();

  private renderer!: THREE.WebGLRenderer;

  private rendererTwo!: THREE.WebGLRenderer;

  private scene!: THREE.Scene;

  private sceneTwo!:THREE.Scene;

  private sceneThree!:THREE.Scene;

  private sceneFour!:THREE.Scene;

  private sceneFive!:THREE.Scene;

  private sceneSix!:THREE.Scene;

  private animateModel() { //for turn
    if (this.model && this.modelTwo && this.modelThree && this.modelFour && this.modelFive && this.modelSix) {
      this.model.rotation.y += 0.001;
      this.modelTwo.rotation.y += 0.001;
      this.modelThree.rotation.y += 0.001;
      this.modelFour.rotation.y += 0.001;
      this.modelFive.rotation.y += 0.001;
      this.modelSix.rotation.y += 0.001;
    }


  }

  private startAnimation = () => {
    const renderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(400, 400);
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'fixed';
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, renderer.domElement);
  };

  /*private createControls = () => {
    const renderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(400, 400);
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'fixed';
    renderer.domElement.style.top = '50%';
    renderer.domElement.style.left = '15%';
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.enableZoom=false;
  };


  private createControlsTwo(cameraTwo: THREE.PerspectiveCamera) {
    const rendererTwo = new CSS2DRenderer();
    rendererTwo.setSize(400, 400);
    rendererTwo.domElement.style.position = 'fixed';
    rendererTwo.domElement.style.top = '50%';
    rendererTwo.domElement.style.left = '45%';
    document.body.appendChild(rendererTwo.domElement);
    const controlsTwo = new OrbitControls(cameraTwo, rendererTwo.domElement);
    controlsTwo.enableZoom = false;

    // Return the controls for the second model
    return controlsTwo;
  }
*/
  private createScene() {
    //* Scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x303B44); //canvas color
    this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/house.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
      this.model = gltf.scene; //without .children cause that loads only one mesh and it's not good
      console.log(this.model);
      var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.model);
      box.getCenter(this.model.position); // this re-sets the mesh position
      this.model.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
      this.scene.add(this.model);
    });
    //*Camera
    let aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    )

    this.camera.position.set(1000,0,-50)
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x00000, 100);
    this.scene.add(this.ambientLight);
    this.directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdf04, 0.4);
    this.directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    this.directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    this.scene.add(this.directionalLight);
    this.light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    this.light1.position.set(0, 200, 400);
    this.scene.add(this.light1);
    this.light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    this.light2.position.set(500, 100, 0);
    this.scene.add(this.light2);
    this.light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    this.light3.position.set(0, 100, -500);
    this.scene.add(this.light3);
    this.light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    this.light4.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
    this.scene.add(this.light4);
  }

  private createSceneTwo() {
    const sceneTwo = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneTwo.background = new THREE.Color(0x303B44); // Canvas color

    this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/Store.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
      this.modelTwo = gltf.scene;
      console.log(this.modelTwo);
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.modelTwo);
      box.getCenter(this.modelTwo.position);
      this.modelTwo.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
      sceneTwo.add(this.modelTwo);
    });

    const aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    const cameraTwo = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );
    cameraTwo.position.set(1000, 0, -50);
    sceneTwo.add(cameraTwo);

    const ambientLightTwo = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000, 100);
    sceneTwo.add(ambientLightTwo);
    const directionalLightTwo = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdf04, 0.4);
    directionalLightTwo.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    directionalLightTwo.castShadow = true;
    sceneTwo.add(directionalLightTwo);
    const light1Two = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light1Two.position.set(0, 200, 400);
    sceneTwo.add(light1Two);
    const light2Two = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light2Two.position.set(500, 100, 0);
    sceneTwo.add(light2Two);
    const light3Two = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light3Two.position.set(0, 100, -500);
    sceneTwo.add(light3Two);
    const light4Two = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light4Two.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
    sceneTwo.add(light4Two);

    return { scene: sceneTwo, camera: cameraTwo };
  }

  private createSceneFour() {
    const sceneThree = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneThree.background = new THREE.Color(0x303B44); // Canvas color

    this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/factory.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
      this.modelFour = gltf.scene;
      console.log(this.modelFour);
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.modelFour);
      box.getCenter(this.modelFour.position);
      this.modelFour.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
      sceneThree.add(this.modelFour);
    });

    const aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    const cameraThree = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );
    cameraThree.position.set(1000, 0, -50);
    sceneThree.add(cameraThree);

    const ambientLightThree = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000, 100);
    sceneThree.add(ambientLightThree);
    const directionalLightThree = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdf04, 0.4);
    directionalLightThree.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    directionalLightThree.castShadow = true;
    sceneThree.add(directionalLightThree);
    const light1Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light1Three.position.set(0, 200, 400);
    sceneThree.add(light1Three);
    const light2Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light2Three.position.set(500, 100, 0);
    sceneThree.add(light2Three);
    const light3Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light3Three.position.set(0, 100, -500);
    sceneThree.add(light3Three);
    const light4Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light4Three.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
    sceneThree.add(light4Three);

    return { scene: sceneThree, camera: cameraThree };
  }

  private createSceneThree() {
    const sceneThree = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneThree.background = new THREE.Color(0x303B44); // Canvas color

    this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/building_2.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
      this.modelThree = gltf.scene;
      console.log(this.modelThree);
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.modelThree);
      box.getCenter(this.modelThree.position);
      this.modelThree.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
      sceneThree.add(this.modelThree);
    });

    const aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    const cameraThree = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );
    cameraThree.position.set(1000, 0, -50);
    sceneThree.add(cameraThree);

    const ambientLightThree = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000, 100);
    sceneThree.add(ambientLightThree);
    const directionalLightThree = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdf04, 0.4);
    directionalLightThree.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    directionalLightThree.castShadow = true;
    sceneThree.add(directionalLightThree);
    const light1Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light1Three.position.set(0, 200, 400);
    sceneThree.add(light1Three);
    const light2Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light2Three.position.set(500, 100, 0);
    sceneThree.add(light2Three);
    const light3Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light3Three.position.set(0, 100, -500);
    sceneThree.add(light3Three);
    const light4Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light4Three.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
    sceneThree.add(light4Three);

    return { scene: sceneThree, camera: cameraThree };
  }

  private createSceneFive() {
    const sceneThree = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneThree.background = new THREE.Color(0x303B44); // Canvas color

    this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/tower.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
      this.modelFive = gltf.scene;
      console.log(this.modelFive);
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.modelFive);
      box.getCenter(this.modelFive.position);
      this.modelFive.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
      sceneThree.add(this.modelFive);
    });

    const aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    const cameraThree = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );
    cameraThree.position.set(1000, 0, -50);
    sceneThree.add(cameraThree);

    const ambientLightThree = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000, 100);
    sceneThree.add(ambientLightThree);
    const directionalLightThree = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdf04, 0.4);
    directionalLightThree.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    directionalLightThree.castShadow = true;
    sceneThree.add(directionalLightThree);
    const light1Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light1Three.position.set(0, 200, 400);
    sceneThree.add(light1Three);
    const light2Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light2Three.position.set(500, 100, 0);
    sceneThree.add(light2Three);
    const light3Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light3Three.position.set(0, 100, -500);
    sceneThree.add(light3Three);
    const light4Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light4Three.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
    sceneThree.add(light4Three);
    return { scene: sceneThree, camera: cameraThree };
  }

  private createSceneSix() {
    const sceneThree = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneThree.background = new THREE.Color(0x303B44); // Canvas color

    this.loaderGLTF.load('assets/bank.gltf', (gltf: GLTF) => {
      this.modelSix = gltf.scene;
      console.log(this.modelSix);
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.modelSix);
      box.getCenter(this.modelSix.position);
      this.modelSix.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
      sceneThree.add(this.modelSix);
    });


    const aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    const cameraThree = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );
    cameraThree.position.set(1000, 0, -50);
    sceneThree.add(cameraThree);

    const ambientLightThree = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000, 100);
    sceneThree.add(ambientLightThree);
    const directionalLightThree = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffdf04, 0.4);
    directionalLightThree.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    directionalLightThree.castShadow = true;
    sceneThree.add(directionalLightThree);
    const light1Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light1Three.position.set(0, 200, 400);
    sceneThree.add(light1Three);
    const light2Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light2Three.position.set(500, 100, 0);
    sceneThree.add(light2Three);
    const light3Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light3Three.position.set(0, 100, -500);
    sceneThree.add(light3Three);
    const light4Three = new THREE.PointLight(0x4b371c, 10);
    light4Three.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
    sceneThree.add(light4Three);

    return { scene: sceneThree, camera: cameraThree };
  }

  private getAspectRatio() {
    return this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight;
  }

  private startRenderingLoop() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvas, antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);
    let component: BlockchainGameComponent = this;
    (function render() {
      component.renderer.render(component.scene, component.camera);
      component.animateModel();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }());
  }

  private startRenderingLoopTwo() {
    const rendererTwo = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvasTwo, antialias: true });
    rendererTwo.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    rendererTwo.setSize(this.canvasTwo.clientWidth, this.canvasTwo.clientHeight);

    const component: BlockchainGameComponent = this;
    (function render() {
      rendererTwo.render(component.sceneTwo, component.camera);
      component.animateModel();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    })();
  }

  private startRenderingLoopThree() {
    const rendererThree = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvasThree, antialias: true });
    rendererThree.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    rendererThree.setSize(this.canvasThree.clientWidth, this.canvasThree.clientHeight);

    const component: BlockchainGameComponent = this;
    (function render() {
      rendererThree.render(component.sceneThree, component.camera);
      component.animateModel();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    })();
  }

  private startRenderingLoopFour() {
    const rendererThree = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvasFour, antialias: true });
    rendererThree.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    rendererThree.setSize(this.canvasFour.clientWidth, this.canvasFour.clientHeight);

    const component: BlockchainGameComponent = this;
    (function render() {
      rendererThree.render(component.sceneFour, component.camera);
      component.animateModel();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    })();
  }

  private startRenderingLoopFive() {
    const rendererThree = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvasFive, antialias: true });
    rendererThree.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    rendererThree.setSize(this.canvasFive.clientWidth, this.canvasFive.clientHeight);

    const component: BlockchainGameComponent = this;
    (function render() {
      rendererThree.render(component.sceneFive, component.camera);
      component.animateModel();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    })();
  }

  private startRenderingLoopSix() {
    const rendererThree = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvasSix, antialias: true });
    rendererThree.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    rendererThree.setSize(this.canvasSix.clientWidth, this.canvasSix.clientHeight);

    const component: BlockchainGameComponent = this;
    (function render() {
      rendererThree.render(component.sceneSix, component.camera);
      component.animateModel();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    })();
  }



  async ngOnInit(){
    this.retrieveData();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createScene();
    const { scene: sceneTwo, camera: cameraTwo } = this.createSceneTwo();
    const { scene: sceneThree, camera: cameraThree } = this.createSceneThree();
    const { scene: sceneFour, camera: cameraFour } = this.createSceneFour();
    const { scene: sceneFive, camera: cameraFive } = this.createSceneFive();
    const { scene: sceneSix, camera: cameraSix } = this.createSceneSix();
    this.sceneTwo = sceneTwo;
    this.cameraTwo = cameraTwo;
    this.sceneThree = sceneThree;
    this.cameraThree = cameraThree;
    this.sceneFour = sceneFour;
    this.cameraFour = cameraFour;
    this.sceneFive = sceneFive;
    this.cameraFive = cameraFive;
    this.sceneSix = sceneSix;
    this.cameraSix = cameraSix;
    this.startRenderingLoop();
    this.startRenderingLoopTwo(); // Start the rendering loop for the second model
    this.startRenderingLoopThree();
    this.startRenderingLoopFour();
    this.startRenderingLoopFive();
    this.startRenderingLoopSix();
    this.startAnimation();
    // @ts-ignore
    //this.controls = this.createControls(this.camera, this.renderer);

  }

}
```

Comment: The HTML markup does not seem consistent  - the first `.arrow` container has a `span` and the others have `p` elements - Is that deliberate?
The final canvas, `id=canvasSix`, has no following `.arrow` container - Is that deliberate?

Comment: yeah guess in testing I forgot to change, they should be all p tags and yeas the last canvas six has no arrow cause it's the last one the idea is to be like canvas ---> canvas two ---> canvas three until canvas six where it ends

Comment: Is there scope to modify the HTML structure to accomplish the desired layout or is that immutable?

Comment: It's immutable, the css won't be changed from the ts file and there is no css alterations in other files